# Logarithm power law discrepancy

Tags: logarithms

According to the power law:-

$$\log_a (x^k) =k\log_a x $$

So take the following example:-

$$\log_2 ((-2)^2) $$

On solving $\log_2 4=2$

However, if we use the power law, then on simplifying, $2\log_2 (-2)$ is not defined.

So how do I justify this?

Comment: Sorry, but does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This dicrepancy is due to the fact that

- $\log x^2$ is defined for $x\neq 0$ but
- $2\log x$ is defined for $x>0$

then the two expression are equal $\iff x>0$.

What is true $\forall x\neq 0$ is that

- $\log x^2=2\log |x|$

where we have used that $\sqrt {x^2}=|x|$.

Comment: So should the law expression be modified?

Comment: @user16701 the definition is valid for positive x values and in this case $\log_a (x^k) =k\log_a x$ is always true https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Definition

Comment: @user16701 as an extension when $x^k$ is positive but $x$ is not the following holds $\log_a (x^k) =k\log_a |x|$

Comment: @gimusi this is true for even $k$, for odd $k$, $\log_a x^k$ is undefined for all $x\le 0$(needless to say, if our codomain is $\Bbb R$)

Comment: @Holo indeed I’ve stated when $x^k$ is positive and if k is odd $x^k$ is positive only for x positive

Comment: @gimusi oh, I read it wrong, sorry. You were completely correct

Comment: @Holo You are welcome, thanks for your comment, many times I get wrong thus I appreciate any check and suggestion given in such constructive form!

Answer (score 1):

The power law is

$$\forall x>0:\log x^k=k\log x.$$

There is no power law for the negatives.

Comment: Consider the problem-

Comment: 2log_3 y -log_3 (y+4) = 2

Comment: Using algebra, the possible solutions are -3,12. However, -3 is not valid on checking. How would you reason this to be excluded?

Comment: @user16701 "$-3$ is outside of our domain, hence the solution is only $12$"

Comment: So can I start by stating that y is positive for 2log_3y to be defined, so when I get a possible solution as -3, I can refer back to this and state this is not a possible solution. Is this a logical reasoning?

Comment: @user16701: this is a different question. Please stop the chat.

Comment: I understand that this is a different question. However, to ask this is a new question would require reference to the original question. And I believe that repetition would be worse.

Comment: @user16701: there is no need of a reference to this question.